# Event handler for close/force stop an ionic app

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic app. I am wondering if there is any event handler for this condition when the app is being stop/close in follow ways:
1) Settings -> Application -> Application Name -> Force stop 
2) Swipe to close app.

I would expect something like this. But the best i could found is to cater for app exiting via `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction` which does not include the above two scenario.

Also, I am not sure whether this can be done in native platform as well. Please advise on this.

```
angular.module('app').run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.onAppStopOrForceClose(function() {
        // Any function here
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ionic.Platform.exitApp(); // stops the app
window.close();
```

see: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

if you try in ios: you can't exit an IOS App, Apple do not allow apps to exit programmatically

Comment: Arent ionic.Platform.exitApp meant to exit the app programmtically? What i want to acheive is call a function before exiting app instead and not a function to exit the app

Comment: You can't do this. And I can't understand why you want to do it.

Comment: @avim101, For example, you want to create a timestamp log when app exits

Comment: @SimonSavai usually you want to write to log when something unexpected is happening.

Comment: @avim101, actually, there are other times when you want to know how people are using your app. So in this case you need informational logs. I've been working on such requirement, and needed to log when an app is launched,  closed etc

Comment: @SimonSavai i can understand the motivation. but for that you can use Analytics services such as google Analytics etc.